# Thread to delay a process when F4 key detected

Tags: c#

Please refer to the following code

```
static class Program
{

    [Flags]
    private enum KeyStates
    {
        None = 0,
        Down = 1,
        Toggled = 2
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

    private static KeyStates GetKeyState(Keys key)
    {
        KeyStates state = KeyStates.None;

        short retVal = GetKeyState((int)key);

        //If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down
        //otherwise, it is up.
        if ((retVal & 0x8000) == 0x8000)
            state |= KeyStates.Down;

        //If the low-order bit is 1, the key is toggled.
        if ((retVal & 1) == 1)
            state |= KeyStates.Toggled;

        return state;
    }

    public static bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
    {
        return KeyStates.Down == (GetKeyState(key) & KeyStates.Down);
    }

    public static bool IsKeyToggled(Keys key)
    {
        return KeyStates.Toggled == (GetKeyState(key) & KeyStates.Toggled);
    }


    private static void DoSomething(object state)
    {
          if (IsKeyDown(Keys.F4)) 
          {
              System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
          }
    }

    [STAThread]

    static void Main()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Application Started");
        System.Threading.Timer myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(DoSomething), null, 0, 1000);
        // execute some long codes here
    }
}
```

Whenever the system detect "F4" keypressed event, it will delay for 30 seconds .. With my current code, it seems like the process never get delayed even though the user pressed key F4...

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to capture the key press via an event rather than checking based on a timer callback, and more importantly the thread sleep will not affect the main thread here, it will sleep the spawned thread that the callback runs on.

Comment: What does it mean to pause the process? Unless that process exposes some kind of IPC interface with a "Delay" method it's not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry I've amended my post. It's not delaying another process, but it will delay the program itself

Answer (score 1):

GetKeyState() can only work properly in a GUI app.  It provides the synchronous state of the key, recorded at the time the key press was detected and added to the message queue.  Important to ensure that the state of the modifier keys can be properly detected for example, they might have changed by the time the keystroke is processed.

This is a console mode app, you must use GetAsyncKeyState() instead.

Comment: I've changed it to GetAsyncKeyState(), but the sleep does not affect the main thread here. What should I do ?

Comment: You should post code that convinces everybody that you can actually *see* the delay.  As posted you can never see it, the timer keeps ticking.  You ought to see a bunch of threads in the Debug + Windows + Threads debugger window, all asleep.  It has no effect on the main thread at all.